# Emacs: how can i just show the next line when i reach the last line of the view?

Tags: emacs

when i move the cursor upwards or downwards and it reach the first/last line of the view (the part of the file that is been showed) it "jumps" so it shows the **before/next half** page of the view instead of just showing the before/next line (like in vi).

So how can i just show the next line?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few different ways of controlling this.  Have a look at the documentation for variables `scroll-step` and `scroll-conservatively`.  Also the manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Auto-Scrolling).

Something like:

```
M-x set-variable<RET> scroll-conservatively<RET> 3<RET>
```

Or more permanently:

```
M-x customize-variable<RET> scroll-conservatively<RET>
```